# Long List Selector with item tap animation

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am working on `Windows Phone 8`, i have long list selector with few items in it.When i tap on the items i need to add some animation to it like, move the text in and come back.How to achieve this? i am trying to apply the same to list box as well.

I have tried this :

```
<Style x:Key="LongListSelectorStyle1" TargetType="phone:LongListSelector">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <UserControl>
                            <Border x:Name="MyBorder" Background="Transparent">
                                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups  >
                                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background)" Storyboard.TargetName="MyBorder">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#000000"/>
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>
                                    </VisualStateGroup>
                                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            </Border>
                        </UserControl>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

But its not working.

Below is the sample screenshot

[image]

How can i achieve this ?

Comment: You define an animation as phone resource and when an item is tapped, run the animation in code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would try using the WPToolkit, in which there is the option where you can apply a 'tilt' animation when an item in your ListBox or LongListSelector is pressed. Very cool. First you need to get the toolkit via NuGet in Visual Studio https://www.nuget.org/packages/WPtoolkit/4.2013.8.16 (a link to the site but you add it using the Package Manager Console within Visual Studio itself and it sets everything up automatically). Check this link http://www.davidsalter.com/2013/09/using-windows-phone-toolkit-in-wp8.html and once you have it, Within the tag wher eyou declared the ListBox or LongListSelector itself, insert the following

```
`<ListBox ... toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True" ../>
```

This should work.