# Installing WP8 XAP file from SDCard

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, xap

I have to send the `XAP file` to my friend and he wants to check the app.Before that i need to test it myself if i add the `XAP file on Sdcard will i be able to install` ?

I have Created a XAP file(Which i have not yet uploaded onto store) and added it into my sdcard.

1) My sdcard is not detecting on the device - In Store option.

2) How to manually install the XAP file.

My device is already registered.

Comment: Use Windowss power tools to install the app, which is not yet in store, make sure the device is developer unlocked

Comment: @JagathMurali Where is this Windowss power tools ?

Comment: you can get it from here : - http://wptools.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks, it worked,i have few more questions can you please help me ?

Comment: Sure, Post your questions, SO is for questions and answers right?

Comment: @JagathMurali yes i have already posted but no answers , Please help me here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22706930/long-list-selector-with-item-tap-animation

Comment: you got an answer there right? i haven't used LonglistSelector in my apps. One thing you can do it update your question or post new question with what ever you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

Publishing to beta takes hardly any effort and since the update it's quite fast. I would recommend for sharing private builds.

[Beta testing your app and in-app products](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/help/jj215598%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)